# Wrong Items Being Deleted in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use local storage to store books for a Library app. I am trying to implement the delete functionality but I am running into issues. When I click the button in the UI to delete an entry, it deletes random books from local storage and not the single book I want to delete. In the UI the correct book is deleted but in local storage it is not behaving like I expected it to. I would appreciate any help I can get. Below is my code:

```
// Book Class
class Book {
    constructor(title, author, pages, bookRead) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author; 
        this.pages = pages;
        this.bookRead = bookRead;
    }
}

//Library Class
class Library {
    static showBook = () => {
        const bookList = UserStorage.getBooks();

        bookList.forEach((book) => Library.addBook(book))
    }
    static addBook = (book) => {
        const displayArea = document.querySelector('.displayArea');
        let newBook = document.createElement('div');
        newBook.classList.add('newEntry');

        let newTitle = document.createElement('div')
        newTitle.classList.add('newTitle', 'cardItem');
        newBook.appendChild(newTitle);
        newTitle.textContent = `Title: ${book.title}`

        let newAuthor = document.createElement('div')
        newAuthor.classList.add('newAuthor', 'cardItem');
        newBook.appendChild(newAuthor);
        newAuthor.textContent = `Author: ${book.author}`
        
        let newPages = document.createElement('div')
        newPages.classList.add('newPages', 'cardItem');
        newPages.textContent = `Pages: ${book.pages}`
        newBook.appendChild(newPages);

        const bookRead = document.querySelector('.hasRead').checked;
        let readSection = document.createElement('button')
        readSection.classList.add('readToggle')
        if(bookRead == true){
            readSection.textContent = 'Read';
        } else {
            readSection.textContent = 'Not Read';
        }
        newBook.appendChild(readSection);

        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
        deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');
        deleteBtn.textContent = 'X';
        newBook.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        displayArea.appendChild(newBook); 
    }
    static clearInput = () => {
        document.querySelector('.title').value = '';
        document.querySelector('.author').value = '';
        document.querySelector('.pages').value = '';
        document.querySelector('.hasRead').value = '';
    }

    static deleteBook = (item) => {
        if(item.classList.contains('deleteBtn')) {
            item.parentElement.remove() 
        }
    }
    static toggleBookRead = (button) => {
        if(button.classList.contains('readToggle')) {
            if(button.textContent === 'Read') {
                button.textContent = 'Not Read'
            } else if (button.textContent === 'Not Read') {
                button.textContent = 'Read'
            }
        }
    }
}

// Local Storage Class
class UserStorage {
    static getBooks = () => {
        let booksInStorage;

        if(localStorage.getItem('booksInStorage') === null) {
            booksInStorage = [];
        } else {
            booksInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('booksInStorage'));
        }
        return booksInStorage;
    }
    static addBook = (book) => {
        const currentBookList = UserStorage.getBooks();
        currentBookList.push(book);
        localStorage.setItem('booksInStorage', JSON.stringify(currentBookList));
    }
    static removeBook = (title) => {
        const currentBookList = UserStorage.getBooks();
        currentBookList.forEach((book, index) => {
            if(title === title) {
                currentBookList.splice(index, 1);
            }
        })
        localStorage.setItem('booksInStorage', JSON.stringify(currentBookList));
    }
}

// Display book in library
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Library.showBook)

// Toggle Add Button
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addBtn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addButton.style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.addBook').style.display = 'block';
})

// Close Form Button
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBtn');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.addBook').style.display = 'none';
    addButton.style.display = 'block';
})

// Add book
document.querySelector('.submitBook').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const title = document.querySelector('[data-title]').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('[data-author]').value;
    const pages = document.querySelector('[data-pages]').value;
    const bookRead = document.querySelector('.hasRead').checked;

    const book = new Book(title, author, pages, bookRead)

    // Add Book to UI
    Library.addBook(book)

    // Add Book to Local Storage
    UserStorage.addBook(book); 

    // Clear Input Fields
    Library.clearInput();
})


// Delete Book
document.querySelector('.displayArea').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Library.deleteBook(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.firstChild)
    UserStorage.removeBook(`${e.target.parentElement.textContent}`)
})

// Mark book as Read/Not Read
document.querySelector('.displayArea').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Library.toggleBookRead(e.target);
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="leftImg" src="Images/pile_of_books.png" alt="Image of Books"><h1 class="mainTitle">My Library</h1><img class="rightImg" src="Images/pile_of_books.png" alt="Image of Books">
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="mainContent">
                <h2 class="libraryTitle">Would you like to add a book to your library?</h2>
                <button class="addBtn">Add</button>
                <div class="addBook">
                    <form class="newBookForm">
                        <button class="closeBtn">X</button>
                        <input data-title class="title" type="text" placeholder="Title">
                        <input data-author class="author" type="text" placeholder="Author">
                        <input  data-pages class="pages" type="number" placeholder="Pages">
                        <label class="readSection" for="hasRead">
                            <label class="readTitle">Have you read this book?</label>
                            <input class="hasRead" type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                        <button class="submitBook">Submit book?</button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="displayArea">
    
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    
</body>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Um `if(title === title) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not manipulate the array from inside a loop:

```
currentBookList.forEach((book, index) => {
            if(title === title) {
                currentBookList.splice(index, 1);
            }
        })
```

What would be better if you find  the index first and then use splice:

```
let index = currentBookList.findIndex((book) => {
            if(title === book.title) 
        {         
             return true;
            }
        })

currentBookList.splice(index, 1);
```

Also, use `book.title` instead of `title === title`

Comment: Where is this index coming from?

Comment: Edited. Thanks @epascarello

Comment: This worked to delete just one item, but now it just deletes the last item from the array. When I console.log() index, it always logs -1. Is there a way to delete a specific item from the array?

Comment: Are you sure the title going in is correct? console.log(title) and see if that is what you expect. Also maybe check if `currentBookList` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I got it now! The title was going in as `Title: ${title}`. I changed it to just go in as `${title}` and that fixed it.